# How to change the locale for testing

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa

I want to set the Locale in my iMac to Thai? Please tell me the steps to do it.

**NOTE: I dont only want to change the language but also the Locale.**

Actually i want to test my Cocoa app for the Thai locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the settings on your computer, you can set the locale for the app to run in instead.

You can create a scheme in Xcode for Thai

And then, in the scheme options go to Edit.

Then, go to the run section and the arguments,

You can then pass in the arguments for thai

[image]

except in your case you need to put the Thai localisation code in place of es.

There is more detail in [this blog post](http://abizern.org/2012/03/18/simple-localisation-testing/)